# What is the meaning of the different cost datasets in AWS Cost Explorer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, billing, aws-cost-explorer

I went through multiple docs but was not able to figure out the appropriate meaning of the AWS Cost Explorer cost datasets:

1. Unblended cost
2. Blended Cost
3. Amortized cost

The docs contain complex definitions that are very difficult to understand. I was seeking When to use these datasets and what are their use-cases in AWS Cost Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

**Blended costs**: uses an average price for each service, regardless of price differences between Reservations or segments. Very good examples here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/con-bill-blended-rates.html

**Unblended costs**: usage cost on the day it is charged to you. This is the one almost everyone uses. The link above can be also helpful to understand it.

**Amortized costs**: recurring costs (such as Reservations, Saving Plans and any upfront costs) are distributed evenly across the month. Useful when making charts and so on.

**Very good link explaining this**: https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws-cloud-financial-management/understanding-your-aws-cost-datasets-a-cheat-sheet/